# Granting a role from a custom command

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I would like to make a custom command for my Discord server, where a user may authenticate using their username and password to obtain a special role. This username and password come from my own application and I would like to have people obtain a "Registered" role when they properly authenticate with the site.

I know that I will need a bot for the server - that's pretty much a no-brainer. But, how do I add a custom command so that people can send in their credentials to allow this? I may also use a temporary hash to avoid logging credentials - but, for now this is just theoretical anyway.

I am using the Discord.js package from NPM, per-se the official API client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic structure for a command is: when you receive a message, check if it's a command and behave accordingly. You should write it like this:

```
client.on('message' , msg => {
  // example: the command is "-test"

  let args = msg.content.split(' '),
    command = args.shift();
  if (command == "-test") {
    ...
  }
});
```

Please note that this is a **very** basic example and that there are more efficient ways to do that (it all depends on what you want to build and how you're going to do that).
To add a role to a member you can use [`GuildMember.addRole()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=addRole), here's an example:

```
let {member} = msg;
if (!member) return msg.reply("You're not in a guild.");
member.addRole('role id here')
  .then(() => msg.reply("Role added."))
  .catch(console.error);
```

Note: If you plan to add a lot of different commands, you may like the [`discord.js-commando`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/commando/master/general/welcome) library: it's a framework built to make command management easier.

This is a quick approach to every part, let me know if you need more info about one aspect.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I'd like to know if, and where messages like that are logged?

Comment: Messages are not logged, so once you delete the message it's gone. If you have to write passwords make sure that the channel where they're sent it's visible only by that user (other users could log them with other scripts). Direct messages would be the perfect thing, because you're sure that they're seen only by the bot and the user. Keep in mind that Discord can read those messages if someone reports an issue to the Trust & Safety team